# how to host multiple virtual hosts from same IP address in Apache server over AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache

I want to host two different angular panels over Apache (AWS). So I disabled the default `000-default.conf` file in `etc/apache2/sites-available` using `a2dissite 000-default.conf` and made two files `webAdmin.conf` and `webUIpanel.conf`. Now my `webAdmin.conf` has the following configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AngularProjects/getItHomeNow_UI/dist

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and `webUIpanel.conf` has following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AngularProjects/getItHomeNow_UserPanel/dist

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I used `a2ensite`  to enable both config files and at last `sudo systemctl restart apache2`. But one of them working at a time. I need to disable one to make other work. Kindly suggest me where did I go wrong?

Comment: You need something to differentiate between both VirtualHost.  Apache will decide based on the IP, the port or the requested domain name.  Here you have none of these 3.  Read  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

You should add `ServerName` in your `VirtualHost` config so Apache can decide which site should get the request. So to apply that to your config it should look like:

`webAdmin.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AngularProjects/getItHomeNow_UI/dist
   ServerName www.example1.com

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and `webUIpanel.conf` has following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/AngularProjects/getItHomeNow_UserPanel/dist
    ServerName www.example2.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

NOTE: Both `ServerName` should be valid domains so they resolve to your server or use your `/etc/hosts` file to point them to your server IP.

Comment: I'm having an IP address . Doesn't have name yet . Should I just use  the IP then?

Comment: You don't need to have an actual name. use your hosts file and put `yourServerIP <space> 
 www.example1.com` and another line for `example2` and It'll work with the above configs.

Comment: ServerName http://3.21.83.36 www.abc.com

You mean like this?

Comment: if this `3.21.83.36` is the server ip. put this in your hosts file ` 3.21.83.36 www.abc.com` and change ServerName to www.abc.com

Comment: by hosts file means, index.html? I've used there href =" "

Comment: well It has started working now I had to give seperate port as 
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>

then 3.21.83.36:81/url